# lombok annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, lombok

I am new to lombok, and I have a project that I have been working on for a while . Everything used to work well until I changed my OS (retaining the code as it was on Bitbucket). Now in am getting an error of

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: 
      private org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory`

probably an issue with lombok version or an issue with the ide.I am using netbean 8

Comment: And the error is? Also this annotation has nothing to do with Spring Boot it is a Lombok annotation.

Answer (score 5):

Use latest lombok version jar in you classpath to work with @Autowired support in @RequiredArgsConstructor. To avoid ide warning, use lombok plugin for your ide, remember to enable annotation processing.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.12</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   *added this after making sure i have the latest version of lombok dependecy* <plugin>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>delombok</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
                    <addOutputDirectory>false</addOutputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```